# Trouble when using OpenGL .obj normals

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to render a cube using an exported.obj file by Blender but the lighting looks like wrong.

I think it's because my vertices array contains 8 values but the normals array has only 6.

I can not understand how OpenGL uses this index array. It's a little bit magic for me.

Can anyone help me?

This is the file:

```
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 0.999999
v -0.999999 1.000000 -1.000001
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000

vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 -0.0000
vn -1.0000 -0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -0.0000 -1.0000
vn 1.0000 -0.0000 0.0000
vn -0.0000 0.0000 1.0000

f 2//1 4//1 1//1
f 8//2 6//2 5//2
f 5//3 2//3 1//3
f 6//4 3//4 2//4
f 3//5 8//5 4//5
f 1//6 8//6 5//6
f 2//1 3//1 4//1
f 8//2 7//2 6//2
f 5//3 6//3 2//3
f 6//4 7//4 3//4
f 3//5 7//5 8//5
f 1//6 4//6 8//6
```

This is my code:

```
GLuint cubeVAO, cubeVerticesVBO, cubeColorsVBO, cubeNormalsVBO, cubeIndicesVBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);


glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVerticesVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVerticesVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_vertices), cube_vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &cubeColorsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeColorsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_colors), cube_colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glGenBuffers(1, &cubeNormalsVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeNormalsVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_normals), cube_normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glGenBuffers(1, &cubeIndicesVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeIndicesVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cube_indices), cube_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);

cubeShader.use();
glm::mat4 model;
cubeShader.setMat4("model", model);
cubeShader.setMat4("view", view);
cubeShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
cubeShader.setVec3("lampColor", lampColor);
cubeShader.setVec3("lampPos", lampPos);
cubeShader.setVec3("viewPos", viewPos);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

out vec3 Color;
out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    vec4 posv4 = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    Color = color;
    FragPos = vec3(model * posv4);
    Normal = normal;
    gl_Position = projection*view*model*posv4;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

in  vec3 Color;
in  vec3 Normal;
in  vec3 FragPos;

out vec4 FragColor;

uniform vec3 lampColor;
uniform vec3 lampPos;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{
    // ambient
    float ambientStrength = 0.1;
    vec3 ambient = ambientStrength * lampColor;

    // diffuse
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lampPos - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lampColor;

    // specular
    float specularStrength = 0.5;
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), 32);
    vec3 specular = specularStrength * spec * lampColor;

    vec3 result = (ambient + diffuse + specular) * Color;
    FragColor = vec4(result, 1.0);
}
```

What's wrong? ,-,

Demonstration video:
https://vid.me/vy17h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to expand the data in the OBJ file. OpenGL expects a normal to be specified for each vertex, individually. In the OBJ file vertices and normals are treated separately. What you have to do is find the unique vertex+normal combinations, store that and index into that new vertex+normal array instead of using separate indices.

With modern OpenGL it is somewhat possible to use different indices for each vertex attribute by making use of vertex shader texture fetch, storing vertex data in textures. But this comes with a performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

The normals array only has 6 values because the cube has 6 faces and you have created a model where each face has 4 normals at the corners pointing in the same direction (ie are identical) - which explains the lighting not looking how you expect.

The obj file uses indexing so it can assign one of these 6 unique values to each of the 8 vertices